# SQLQuery for multiple tables for specific records in T1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write select query to extract data as below:

```
T1 
PARTN     DESCRIPTION
xx1       mouse      
xx2       Kb

T2 
PARTN COIN PRC1 PRC2    
xx1   usd  2    4 
xx1   eur  1    2 
xx2   usd  4    8
xx2   eur  3    6
```

Ideal query result

```
PARTN    PRCUSD1 PRCUSD2 PRCEUR1 PRCEUR2  
xx1      2       4       1       2
xx2      4       8       3       6
```

Is it possible?
See Image.

[image: Image of Tables]

Comment: Your image doesnt match your data.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using

Comment: HINT: look for `PIVOT`

Comment: Hi, thanks. You are right its wrong. Its suppose to be like the last table from the image. DB is in SQL server, and i'm using sql management studio. The idea is to find a query that returns correctly and then use it in a vba project.

Comment: the table one doesnt accept duplicates on "partn" but the second one does because I can add as much coins as I want. and thats were I cant find a way to select a product and show all prices in the same row.

Comment: Juan corrected data to match image.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the currencies in advance then just use multiple joins. If that's not true then you'll probably need a dynamic SQL solution.

```
select
    p.PARTN,
    usd.PRC1 as PRCUSD1, usd.PRC2 as PRCUSD2,
    eur.PRC1 as PRCEUR1, eur.PRC2 as PRCEUR2
from
    T1 p
    inner join T2 usd on usd.PARTN = p.PARTN and usd.COIN = 'usd'
    inner join T2 eur on eur.PARTN = p.PARTN and eur.COIN = 'eur'
```

Comment: Sorry not getting were are you selecting "usd.PRC1" Column?

Comment: @Nimuloid from table T2. I don't really understand your question.